# No response from pyserial connection to android on serial port

Tags: python, android, linux, serial-port, pyserial

Trying to communicate with an android device on a serial port.  I can establish a connection through pyserial, but I don't understand how the flow of information works and why I can't get any output (or when I should expect output).  As a check, I can log into the device using `minicom` or `python3 -m serial.tools.miniterm` and get the expected output from things like `pwd` and `echo hello`.  My basic code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0")
ser.write(b'echo hello')
ser.inWaiting()
ser.write(b'pwd')
ser.inWaiting()
# print(ser.readLine().decode())
```

`ser.inWaiting()` returns `0` both times it's called, so there's no point in trying to read anthing.

I would greatly appreciate any discussion of fundamentals that I seem to be missing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your `port`, `baudrate`, `parity` and `stopbits` with the minicom setting and pass those keywords to [serial.Serial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html). You did not set a baudrate and [serial.Serial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)'s default of 9600 B is probably wrong. 115200 B would be my first guess.

On a general note:

1. The [short introduction](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) shows the usage of [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io).
2. When reading a fixed number of bytes with `read()` or until and end of line character with `read_until`, ensure that the timeout is not set too low.
3. Ensure that only one instance open and closes the serial port. A port can be opened multiple times, but that leads to unexpected behavior.
4. When using `inWaiting()` you to wait a while for the answer first(300 ms would be good starting point)—serial communication is so slow!

Answer (score 0):

The return of `ser.inWaiting` will be the number of bytes on input buffer. The code below writes your first message and waits if something is entered on input buffer then will read what come to you:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("dev/ttyS0")
while 1:
    ser.write(b'echo hello')
    if ser.inWaiting()>0:
        ser.read(32)# the argument is the number of bytes to read
```

Comment: sorry for the bad anwser i am new here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.